# Unable to get asynchronous child spawning in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to format this code in such a way that when a user clicks a button, new input fields each with a redirect button gets inserted asynchronously into the un-ordered list, it worked up until i added the redirect button to also be inserted upon each click of the spawn button. 
Here is my JS code...

```
function spawnSilly()
        {
            var div = document.createElement("DIV");
            var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
            var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var att1 = document.createAttribute("type")
            var att2 = document.createAttribute("placeholder")
            var att3 = document.createAttribute("type")
            var att4 = document.createAttribute("onClick")
            att1.value = "text"
            att2.value = "Title"
            att3.value = "button"
            att4.value = "redirect()"
            input.setAttributeNode(att1)
            input.setAttributeNode(att2)
            button.setAttribute(att3)
            button.setAttribute(att4)
            div.appendChild(input)
            div.appendChild(button);

            var list = document.getElementById("spawnList");
            list.insertBefore(div, list.childNodes[0]);
        }
```

This is my HTML

```
<ul id="spawnList">


</ul>
<button id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly()">Add</button>
```

Seems to be the button thats causing the issue, but i can't figure out why?
Any help would be awesome! thanks

Comment: I think you have things in the wrong order, add the elements to the dom before you add child-elements to them. But add attributes before you add the elements to the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) takes two arguments, the `name` of the attribute and the `value`. Using this in the right way, the code can be simplified like this:

```js
function redirect()
{
    console.log("Redirect clicked!");
}

function spawnSilly()
{
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Title");
    button.setAttribute("type", "button");
    button.setAttribute("onClick", "redirect()");
    button.innerHTML = "Redirect";
    div.appendChild(input)
    div.appendChild(button);

    var list = document.getElementById("spawnList");
    list.insertBefore(div, list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<ul id="spawnList"></ul>
<button id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! so was it the fact that my syntax for the attribute() was wrong?

Comment: @akemedis Mainly yes (only in the button), the usage of `setAttributeNode()` is fine. But in the button you was using `setAttribute()`. The easy fix will be replacing that by `setAttributeNode()`.

Answer (score 0):

`setAttribute` take two parameters, first is the `name` of attribute and second is `value`, but you have only one - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute.

Instead you can set the value to attributes using `.` operator.

Also, you are attaching a function call `att4.value = "redirect()"`. So, whenever the button gets added your `redirect` will get called. Instead attach a `callback` to `redirect`, so it gets called when the button is `clicked`.

```js
function spawnSilly()
{
    const div = document.createElement("DIV");
    const input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    const button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = "Title";
    
    button.type ="button";
    button.onclick = redirect;
    button.textContent = "Click Me!";

    div.appendChild(input)
    div.appendChild(button);

    const list = document.getElementById("spawnList");
    list.insertBefore(div, list.childNodes[0]);
}

function redirect() {
    console.log('In redirect');
}
```

```html
<ul id="spawnList">
</ul>
<button id="spawnbtn" onClick="spawnSilly()">Add</button>
```

Comment: the redirect is the value of the onClick attribute, wouldn't that mean that it would only trigger when the user clicks the button? not every time its called